# for a server with potentially long execution time, how to return result to a user timely and do not overload the server with excessive requests?

Tags: php

I have a server with a web interface, through which a task is submitted to the server and the result is returned to the user as a web page. Sometimes the result is generated on the fly, sometimes it may take several hours. The result is written on disk and `check_status` function periodically checks whether the task is completed.
In the code given below it seems

```
while ($status == 0) {
    sleep(x);
    $status = check_status($pars);
    ...
}
```

hangs up the server for big tasks when the user waits until his or her task will be completed.
What would be the optimal solution to return the result to the user timely and not overload
the server with excessive requests?
Set up a limit in the loop and terminate it? Or are there modern advanced technologies to
handle these situations more efficiently?

```
$status = check_status($pars);
if ($status == 1) {
    ...
    print $result;
}
else {
    print $reference_to_future_result; 
}

ob_flush();
flush();

while ($status == 0) {
    sleep(30);
    $status=check_status($pars);
    if ($status == 1) {
        ...
        change_page_content_to_result;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Have you looked into the [flush](http://php.net/flush) function?

Comment: If you're using Apache, `sleep()` is going to lock up an entire Apache progress for that time period. Generally a bad idea unless you want to get DOSed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If open connections to your server is an issue, I would suggest periodically polling from the client side using AJAX. The client would check in every so often, and your server would return the status of your job in a simple HTTP response.

I would recommend building something using JavaScript's `setInterval()` and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s AJAX functionality.

Comment: no. this wont work, even if you run it by ajax the request still blocking other requests.

Comment: My answer implies that none of the requests are blocking. Think of it like checking on the status of a background process in linux. Each AJAX request merely checks on the status of a job. Your job itself is submitted and run in the background (not blocking HTTP).

Comment: if we were actually talking non blocking requests `not overload the server with excessive requests` wont be part of the question right?

Comment: I wouldn't consider a ~20ms request every 5 seconds or so excessive by any means...

Comment: thanks for the reply, still don't see advantage of your suggestion. May be I'm missing something. You suggest to move the loop to client side. The number of requests check_status calls still will be the same. The difference - in your case they will be external calls to the server.                                                                The point is that the loop is infinite. What happens if the task crushes = will never generate the result...

Comment: Whatever you want really. If you're really expecting a (virtually) infinite loop, all the more reason to not leave an HTTP request open. If your task crashes, report it as crashed. You can avail yourself of wonderful techniques such as pid files and process signalling to communicate with and check the status of other processes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to decouple this process from the webserver otherwise will keep blocking requests

I see some options

- Use a cronjob that reads a job queue from the db (for example) and process the job. The only cons I see here is your minimum frequency will be 1 minute. so you just need to save the workload and set a record on the db so this can be picked by the script that was cronted
- Use a job server (such as gearman, to name one) that is constantly listening for new jobs, do a `fire and forget` request
- Use a non blocking server: node.js, tornado, etc... (this make no sense at all, but worth to mention)

for both uses you will need to use some way to track progress, you could use db or memory (memcache, redis, etc) and then have a js functions that keep asking the progress of the task.